# How many seasons did Steve Young play?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

Steve Young, in [an interview](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/sports/league-of-denial/the-frontline-interview-steve-young/), stated that he played 18 seasons of football.

However, if you look at [the Wikipedia page on him](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Young), it lists 17 seasons (15 in the NFL, 2 in the USFL), not 18.

How can this discrepancy be resolved? I'd like to think that you could trust his own word on this over Wikipedia, but at the same time I just don't see how he came up with 18, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I wouldn't trust his word over solid records-keeping. Simple as that.

Comment: Seems like he said 18 seasons, then 18 years (not the same) then 17, 18 seasons. He's not being exact. Not sure it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Steve Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Young) played 17 seasons (15 in the NFL, 2 in the USFL).

Sources: [pro-football-reference](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/Y/YounSt00.htm), [britannica](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Steve-Young), [nfl.com](http://www.nfl.com/player/steveyoung/2503843/careerstats), [cbsnews](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/steve-youngs-mental-struggle-off-the-playing-field/), [profootballhof](http://www.profootballhof.com/players/steve-young/), [totalfootballstats](http://www.totalfootballstats.com/PlayerQB.asp?id=4312), [wbur.org](http://www.wbur.org/onlyagame/2016/11/18/steve-young-usfl-40-million)

IMO, he intended to say "I played almost 18 seasons." instead of "[I played 18 seasons.](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/sports/league-of-denial/the-frontline-interview-steve-young/#seg5)" in that interview. Even if he have calculated his NCAA career that would make it 19 different year. 
[image: Steve young Career]

Comment: I know there is opinion, but so many source with 17 season (there may be others) it doesn't matter whether he says 17 or 18.